# SQL group by - match all items in a given list

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, relational-division

I have a table like below:

| id | device_id | device_model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | A |
| 1 | 201 | B |
| 1 | 202 | B |
| 2 | 102 | A |
| 2 | 301 | C |
| 3 | 103 | A |
| 3 | 203 | B |
| 3 | 302 | C |

I want to select group of ids with specific device models given in a list. At first, I tried:

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl
WHERE device_model IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY id
```

But this works like `OR`... if an id has only one of `('A', 'B')` it is returned. This is not the behavior I want, instead I want `AND` behavior.

I thought I can use this:

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl
WHERE device_model IN ('A', 'B')
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT device_model) = 2;
```

But, this returns id 1 and 3; but I only want 1, not 3... since it also has device model C.

What can I do to get ids that contain **exactly** those device models given in a list?

Comment: Skip the WHERE clause. Use HAVING to make sure only A and B are there.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `GROUP BY` clause and one more condition inside the `HAVING` clause, that checks the presence of only A,B inside the field device_model.

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT device_model) = 2
   AND MIN(device_model IN ('A', 'B')) = 1;
```

This should work on MySQL, and should generalize well on any n amount of elements you want to check. It would suffice to add all your elements inside the array, and update the number of distinct elements.

**Output**:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8feFEaXU4kXDcPj2mQVoHS/1).

Comment: `case` was fine. without it, it wont work on sql server, a common rdbms.

Comment: @lemon, you're correct! My bad.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HAVING clause along with conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN device_model IN ('A', 'B') THEN device_model END) = 2
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN device_model NOT IN ('A', 'B') THEN device_model END) = 0;
```

In this query, we use conditional aggregation to count the distinct device_models that match the specified models and those that don't. The CASE statement is used to conditionally count the values based on the IN and NOT IN conditions.

The HAVING clause then checks if the count of matching device_models is equal to the number of specified models (2 in this case) and the count of non-matching device_models is 0. This ensures that only the id groups having all the specified models and none of the others are selected.

Answer (score 2):

A completely different approach:

```
select id from tbl where device_model = 'A'
intersect
select id from tbl where device_model = 'B'
except
select id from tbl where device_model not in ('A', 'B');
```

I did some basic performance tests, and this query was actually several times faster than all of the GROUP BY/HAVING queries I tried. (Not run on MySQL though.)

My best performing GROUP BY/HAVING query is:

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(case when device_model not in ('A', 'B') then 1 end) = 0
   AND MIN(device_model) <> MAX(device_model);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your first approach is a bit limited for my case, because it requires selecting for each model. Instead, I need a more dynamic solution like your GROUP BY/HAVING query where I can easily use a dynamic list of models. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to test for "relational division remainder" you must get rid of `where` clause and add an additional condition in `having` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT device_model) = 2
AND    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN device_model IN ('A', 'B') THEN device_model END) = 2
```